# Randomized algorithm for finding a prime number between $n$ and $2n$

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, random, primality-test

I have already seen some threads conjecturing that there is at least one prime between $n$ and $2n$. I am given an exercise, where I have relaxed this conjecture to the assumption that between $n$ and $2n$ there are at least $\frac{n}{3\ln n}$ primes. I am asked to describe a randomized algorithm to find a prime in the range $n$ and $2n$ with probability $1 - \frac{1}{n}$.

The only possible solution, that I could think of is to pick random numbers in the range $n$ and $2n$ and apply Miller-Rabin, until Miller-Rabin returns a probably prime. Problem here is that, probably prime is correct with probability $\frac{3}{4}$, which is too far from $1 - \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: There is nothing better, apart from beginning with trial division upto some limit, say , $1\ 000$. Good news : The probability of a false result is in almost every case much smaller than $1/4$ (the worst case, if you only check one base). Also, the result "composite" is always correct. The chance that you hit a number with a "high" probability to be falsely screened as a prime is very low.

Comment: If your number is not too big (say not more than $500$ digits) , then there are still fast primality proofs (if you actually want to be 100% sure that you found a prime)

Comment: This is not a conjecture, [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) has even been strengthened some.

Comment: I am trying to find an efficient randomized algorithm giving me result with guaranteed a lot higher probability than 3/4.

Comment: The standard way to test probable primes is to re-run Miller-Rabin several times on the same number with different seeds. For one run, the probability of error is 1/4; with k runs, the probability of error is 1/4^k.

Comment: You can also check $n$ Miller Rabin random bases , where $n$ is large enough such that $(1/4)^n$ is smaller than the probability you need.

Comment: Hmm then it seems that the condition that the prime number is between $n$ and $2n$ did not play any role here, and also the assumption on number of primes is disregarded, right?

Comment: It only plays a role in the sense that it determines the probability you need. If you want to stop as soon as an example has been found, I suggest to calculate the number of random bases you need that $1-1/(2n)$ is beaten. You won't need too many bases , if $n$ is reasonably small. For small $n's$ , there are morevoer combinations proving the primality if the test is passed.

Comment: And yes , the number of primes is irrelevant for the problem. Searching near $n$ makes a number slightly more probable to be a prime , so beginning with $n$ is not the worst idea.

Comment: But the effect is so small that taking random numbers is better since then you have a very little risk that the first probable prime turns out to be composite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after following the discussion, what I suggested is the right approach. Plus, one needs to repeat RM sufficient number of times to get the desired probability. To determine the number of repetitions, use Chernoff bound, which takes into account the number of primes within the selected range.